# How do you get Geofencing to work in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, geofencing, android-geofence

for days now im stuck. I am trying to do a simple toast when a user enters or leaves a geo fence to see if its working. And there IS NO GOOD step by step tutorial online that shows me how to do it. (The ones by google don't show me how to toast or do anything at all...)

Here is my main activity's code.

```
    public class GeoFence extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, ResultCallback<Status> {
        private static final String GEOFENCE_ID = "geoFenceID" ;
        protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        private Button mAddGeofencesButton;
        private Button startLocationMonitoringButton;
        private Button startGeoFenceMonitoringButton;
        private Button stopGeoFenceMonitoringButton;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_geo_fence);
            mAddGeofencesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_geofences_button);
            startLocationMonitoringButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.geoButton1);
            startLocationMonitoringButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startLocationMonitoring();
                }
            });
            startGeoFenceMonitoringButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.geoButton2);
            startGeoFenceMonitoringButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startGeofenceMonitoring();
                }
            });

            stopGeoFenceMonitoringButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.geoButton3);
            stopGeoFenceMonitoringButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    stopGeoFenceMonitoring();
                }
            });
    }

    private void startLocationMonitoring() //Make a button for this
    {
        try {
            LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create().setInterval(10000)
                    .setFastestInterval(5000)
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
                {

                }
            });
        }
        catch (SecurityException e)
        {

        }
    }

    private void startGeofenceMonitoring() //Make a button for this
    {
        try
        {
            Geofence geofence = new Geofence.Builder()
                    .setRequestId(GEOFENCE_ID)
                    .setCircularRegion(34.065866, -118.459572,45)
                    .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                    .setNotificationResponsiveness(1000)
                    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                    .build();

            GeofencingRequest geofencingRequest = new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
                    .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
                    .addGeofence(geofence).build();

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceService.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            if(!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
            {
                //Toast not connected
            }
            else
            {
                LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(mGoogleApiClient, geofencingRequest,pendingIntent)
                        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                                if(status.isSuccess())
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"successful monitoring...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //Something fucked up with our geofence bro
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
        catch (SecurityException e)
        {

        }
    }

    private void stopGeoFenceMonitoring()
    {
        ArrayList<String> geofenceIds = new ArrayList<>();
        geofenceIds.add(GEOFENCE_ID);
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(mGoogleApiClient,geofenceIds);
    }
}
```

Here is my GeofenceService class, where i think im suppose to toast?

```
public class GeofenceService extends IntentService
{

    /**
     * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
     *
     * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
     */
    public static final String TAG = "GeofenceService";
    public GeofenceService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        GeofencingEvent event = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if(event.hasError())
        {

        }
        else
        {
            int transition = event.getGeofenceTransition();
            List<Geofence> geofences = event.getTriggeringGeofences();
            Geofence geofence = geofences.get(0);
            String requestId = geofence.getRequestId();
            if(transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Entering GeoFence",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Leaving GeoFence",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally here is my xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_geofences_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:onClick="addGeofencesButtonHandler"
        android:text="Add GeoFences" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start Location Monitoring"
        android:id="@+id/geoButton1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start GeoFence Monitoring"
        android:id="@+id/geoButton2"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Stop GeoFence Monitoring"
        android:id="@+id/geoButton3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

If any of you guys have SIMPLE step by step (no code missing) tutorials or code about how to do a simple geofence with a display toast of entering or exiting geofence thatd be great! And/or can you also check my existing code to see if im missing something. THE CODE RUNS, but nothing happens...

Comment: 1. In your onHandleIntent you only look at your first geofence. 2. The tutorial has a section 5 with code. 3. How are you testing your geofence (device/emulator/mock geo app) ? 4.4. A slightly different google sample for geofence is here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Geofencing

Comment: @MorrisonChang 1. So i only set up one geofence on purpose just to see if i can make it work with one geofence. Am i suppose to have more than 1 geofences, and what do you mean by "looking"? 2. Are you referring to the tutorial you posted, which tutorial are you referring to? 3. I am testing on device, so i am physically walking into a geofence to see if it would toast. Thanks for the first reply, hopefully you can answer my next questions.

Comment: 1. "look" = reference - as you only using the first proximity entry - you should be fine 2. The tutorial you linked to in your earlier question: http://io2015codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/geofences#5 3. I would lengthen your notificationResponse to more than 1 second. Especially if using a device as power management See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25785404/295004 As an alternative to testing by physically moving the device, you may want to try a Mock Geo Provider.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Do you have a reference to the mock geo provider?

Comment: @MorrisonChang and so you see nothing wrong with the code? I will try to increase the the notification response time.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. `GoogleApiClient` is depricated now. This class is spitted in several other: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-api-client . Now you need to use `GeofenceClient`, which has really similar approach.

https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing

**In short**, you just need to use `GeofencingClient` instead of `GoogleApiClient`.

```
private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
    // Reuse the PendingIntent if we already have it.
    if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
    // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when
    // calling addGeofences() and removeGeofences().
    mGeofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.
            FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    return mGeofencePendingIntent;
}
```

Use link provided above for full example.